# quarkus(vertx) how to get request body in a blocking way

Tags: jax-rs, quarkus, vert.x

- **What I've tried:**

inject `CurrentVertxRequest` context and then get body from there

```java
@Path("/map_event")
public class MapEventApi {

    @Inject
    CurrentVertxRequest reqContext;
  

    @POST
    @Consumes({ "application/json" })
    @Produces({ "application/json" })
    Response create(@Valid MapEvent mapEvent, @Context SecurityContext securityContext) throws Exception {
        String body = reqContext.getCurrent().getBodyAsString();
        ...
    }

}
```

but this will give a warning:

```
2022-01-25 18:22:08,854 WARN  [null:-1] (executor-thread-0) BodyHandler in not enabled on this route: RoutingContext.getBodyAsString(...) in always be NULL
```

- **another try:**

inject standard JaxRS `HttpServletRequest` context

```
@Context HttpServletRequest
```

will get this error:

```
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.LoggableFailure: RESTEASY003880: Unable to find contextual data of type: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ContextParameterInjector$GenericDelegatingProxy.invoke(ContextParameterInjector.java:155)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy97.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
```

I guess it's because quarkus use vertx under the hood so injecting regular jaxrs context won't work since it's not the same thread.

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: @geoand I've updated the code to original post

Comment: And what are you trying to read the body as?

Comment: @geoand want to read the body as string, and do some further process

Comment: Did you try adding `String body` as a parameter of `create`?

Comment: @geoand actually the `MapEvent mapEvent` parameter capture the body, converted by jackson automatically. But I still want to examine the raw body in the interceptor for logging purpose

Comment: The body is only read once. If you need the raw form, I suggest using that as method parameter and then do the mapping manually in the method body

Comment: @geoand that makes sense, thanks for the suggestion:)

Answer (score 2):

According to @geoand proposiiton following solution worked for me:

```java
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
Response create(String body) throws Exception {
    ...
}
```

> consuming the request as `String` was the trick → `@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)`